# Regression not working

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to run a simple regression using the following code:

```
reg1 <- lm(MCBClose ~ MCBOpen + MCBVolume + MCBHigh + MCBLow + PSX100, data = data2)
plot(reg1)
summary(reg1)
```

This should be simple enough and I've done similar regressions numerous times but when I am running this, it is treating **all** entries in my dataset as coefficients and is producing a giant summary table with many NAs. What's happening? I think its a problem with my data frame. How should I fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately, your code is not reproducible.

Comment: You have factor variables in your dataset. Check str(data2).

Comment: Hi! Yeah I figured that out but am really confused about how to fix this. I applied the following code :-

for (j in 1:6){
  for (i in 1:84){
    bigdata[i,j] <- as.numeric(as.character(bigdata[i,j]))
  }
}

Then I checked the class and mode. The mode is all numeric (it wasn't so before but just fixed that). But the class is still factors. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: If you change single elements and assign them back to the column the elements are coerced to the column's type and class. You need to change the whole column at once, e.g. bigdata[] <- lapply(bigdata, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))). However, you should find out why your data is not numeric to begin with.